# Netbeans IDE 8.0 'mutex' does not name a type

Tags: c++11, netbeans

I am using netbeans IDE 8.0 with mingw-builds\x32-4.8.1 compiler.

I have included mutex header file and declared 'using namespace std' directive

But the IDE reports unresolved identifier for mutex type. Compilation also fails.

```
g++ -m32   -c -O2 -I../../../../../Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/mingw-builds/x32-4.8.1-win32-dwarf-rev5/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++ -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Release/MinGW_1-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Release/MinGW_1-Windows/main.o main.cpp
main.cpp:25:5: error: 'mutex' does not name a type
     mutex mu;
```

The include path in the above command has the mutex header file. Tried Clean and Build, Code Assistance->Reparse Project, nothing resolves this.

Any idea how do I get this working ? Netbeans IDE 8.0 is up to date.

**EDIT:** I see in the header file mutex there are two #ifdefs for _GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS and _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_STDINT_TR1 under which all the mutex related classes are defined.
Do I need to pass these macros as compiler options ?

Comment: What happens if you add `std::` before `mutex` (even with `using namespace` directive) ?

Comment: I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Is resolved now.  There is an option while installing mingw 4.8.1 compiler to select either win32 threads or posix threads. I had selected win32. My guess is that win32 threads version does not define the _GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS macro.

I uninstalled and reinstalled selecting posix threads and very thing works fine now.